# .NET Core middleware throws stream error on POST actions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-3.1

[image]

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Context;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HMS.Api
{
    public class SerilogMiddleware
    {
        const string MessageTemplate = "HTTP {RequestMethod} {RequestPath} responded {StatusCode} in {Elapsed:0.0000} ms";
        static readonly ILogger Log = Serilog.Log.ForContext<SerilogMiddleware>();
        readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public SerilogMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));

            // Start timing the call...
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();

            // Push the user name into the log context so that it is included in all log entries
            LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", httpContext.User.Identity.Name);

            // Getting the request body is a little tricky because it's a stream
            // So, we need to read the stream and then rewind it back to the beginning
            string requestBody = "";
            //httpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
            using (Stream body = httpContext.Request.Body)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(httpContext.Request.ContentLength)];
                await httpContext.Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                httpContext.Request.Body = body;
            }

            var request = httpContext.Request;
            var log = Log
                .ForContext("RequestHeaders", request.Headers.ToDictionary(h => h.Key, h => h.Value.ToString()), destructureObjects: true)
                .ForContext("RequestScheme", request.Scheme)
                .ForContext("RequestHost", request.Host)
                .ForContext("RequestProtocol", request.Protocol)
                .ForContext("RequestBody", requestBody.IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? "n/a" : requestBody)
                .ForContext("RequestPath", request.Path);
            if (request.QueryString.HasValue)
                log = log.ForContext("RequestQueryString", request.QueryString.Value);
            if (request.HasFormContentType)
                log = log.ForContext("RequestForm", request.Form.ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.Value.ToString()));

            // The reponse body is also a stream so we need to:
            // - hold a reference to the original response body stream
            // - re-point the response body to a new memory stream
            // - read the response body after the request is handled into our memory stream
            // - copy the response in the memory stream out to the original response stream
            using (var responseBodyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var originalResponseBodyReference = httpContext.Response.Body;
                httpContext.Response.Body = responseBodyMemoryStream;

                try
                {
                    await _next(httpContext);
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Guid errorId = Guid.NewGuid();
                    Log.ForContext("Type", "Error")
                        .ForContext("Exception", exception, destructureObjects: true)
                        .Error(exception, exception.Message + ". {@errorId}", errorId);

                    httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                    httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
                    await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorFormat
                    {
                        StatusCode = httpContext.Response.StatusCode,
                        Message = "Internal Server Error"
                    }.ToString());
                }

                var statusCode = httpContext.Response?.StatusCode;

                httpContext.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var responseBody = await new StreamReader(httpContext.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                httpContext.Response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                log = log.ForContext("ResponseBody", responseBody);

                if (statusCode < 400)
                    log.Information(MessageTemplate, httpContext.Request.Method, httpContext.Request.Path, statusCode, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
                else
                    log.Error(MessageTemplate, httpContext.Request.Method, httpContext.Request.Path, statusCode, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

                await responseBodyMemoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBodyReference);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure the error is happening in the QA/Stage environment when control is passed on to `await _next(httpContext);`

Every article I've found, every help page from MS, all of them point to handling the streams this way.  And so far it works great local with a postman for the frontend but publish it and let the UI make the call and every single POST/PUT fails.  So, trying to pass on the request body is munching up and I am not seeing why!

Thoughts?

NOTE:
.NET Core 3.1
C#
MVC API

Comment: You are disposing of the body on this line: `using (Stream body = httpContext.Request.Body)` Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't wrap the`Stream body` in a using block. Because it is a reference variable, it will also dispose of the request body stream. I don't think your using block is doing what you intend - although, to be fair, I'm not sure what you're expecting it to do anyways.

Deploying a release build would have more optimistic garbage collection, which could explain the more eager dispose behavior and exception when not running locally.

The using block code would be completely replaced with this (no using block):

```
string requestBody = "";
httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering(); // enable the stream to be read multiple times
byte[] buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(httpContext.Request.ContentLength)];
await httpContext.Request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
httpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

var request = httpContext.Request;
```

Comment: I need to track down the reference for `httpContext.Request.EnableRewind();`  It keeps showing up as an unknown method.

Comment: nm   ...consider the following HTTP request buffering code in an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project. The EnableRewind extension method exists in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal namespace.

`HttpContext.Request.EnableRewind();`  
In an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project, replace the EnableRewind call with a call to the EnableBuffering extension method. The request buffering feature works as it did in the past. EnableBuffering calls the now internal API.

`HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();`

Comment: @KeithBarrows Good catch. Did the above work for you, or is it still throwing the exception? When you test locally, try running in release mode instead of debug for this issue. Release mode will help early dispose issues show themselves. The JIT compiler doesn't dispose as early in debug mode.

Comment: I will know for sure in the morning.  It is already past midnight and I have stand up first thing in the morning.  A quick test seemed to work so I am hopeful.  I had to add a `var body = ...` statement as that part was missing...